# QtConcurrent::run() can't handle more than 5 arguments?

Tags: c++, qt, compiler-errors, qtconcurrent

I'm getting a compile error when passing a function with 6 parameters or more to `QtConcurrent::run()`. When I reduce them to 5 parameters, I no longer get this error.

This dummy code reproduces the error for me:

```
void foo(int, int, int, int, int, int)
{

}

QtConcurrent::run(foo, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
```

The compiler error is:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'run(void (&)(int, int, int, int, int, int), int, int, int, int, int, int)'
```

Is this supposed to be so? Is `QtConcurrent::run()` really limited to 5 arguments at most?

Comment: It woudln't surprise me if it was limited. It has to work with pre-C++11 compilers, after all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See *qtconcurrentrun.h*

```
template <typename T, typename Param1, typename Arg1, typename Param2, typename Arg2, typename Param3, typename Arg3, typename Param4, typename Arg4, typename Param5, typename Arg5>
QFuture<T> run(T (*functionPointer)(Param1, Param2, Param3, Param4, Param5), const Arg1 &arg1, const Arg2 &arg2, const Arg3 &arg3, const Arg4 &arg4, const Arg5 &arg5);
```

There are 5 arguments that function can take

Answer (score 6):

On the one side, you can use `std::bind` or `boost::bind` to pass more then 5 arguments (unlimited in case of C++11):

```
QFuture<void> result = QtConcurrent::run(std::bind(&foo, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6));
```

On the other side, 5 arguments *should be* enough for every function. You may want reconsider your design to decrease the number of function parameters. You can pass some object to function instead.

```
Data d;
QFuture<void> result = QtConcurrent::run(foo, d);
```

Also don't forget that Concurrent::run can [hung](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-3786) sometimes with no reason in pre-5.3 builds.